# No rule to make target all.R, needed by compiler.rdb R 3.4.1 from source, Scientific Linux

Tags: r, gcc, redhat

I am trying to build R from source on Scientific Linux release 6.9 (Carbon), Linux version 2.6.32-696.3.2.el6.x86_64 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18).

I load the needed modules and run:

```
./configure --prefix $install_dir --with-blas --with-lapack --enable-R-shlib 2>&1 | tee config-R-$version.log
```

The "configure" command seems to run ok:

```
R is now configured for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

  Source directory:          .
  Installation directory:    /fastdata/mbp15ja/R-3.4.1

  C compiler:                gcc  -I/usr/local/packages6/compilers/gcc/5.4.0/include
  Fortran 77 compiler:       gfortran  -g -O2

  Default C++ compiler:      g++   -g -O2
  C++98 compiler:            g++  -g -O2
  C++11 compiler:            g++ -std=gnu++11 -g -O2
  C++14 compiler:            g++ -std=gnu++14 -g -O2
  C++17 compiler:
  Fortran 90/95 compiler:    gfortran -g -O2
  Obj-C compiler:

  Interfaces supported:      X11, tcltk
  External libraries:        readline, curl
  Additional capabilities:   PNG, JPEG, NLS, cairo
  Options enabled:           shared R library, shared BLAS, R profiling

  Capabilities skipped:      TIFF, ICU
  Options not enabled:       memory profiling

  Recommended packages:      yes
```

I encountered an error running "make -n" with the libtre library not generating libtre.a:

```
rm -rf libnmath.a
ar -cr libnmath.a mlutils.o d1mach.o i1mach.o fmax2.o fmin2.o fprec.o fround.o ftrunc.o sign.o fsign.o imax2.o imin2.o chebyshev.o log1p.o expm1.o lgammacor.o gammalims.o stirlerr.o bd0.o gamma.o lgamma.o gamma_cody.o beta.o lbeta.o polygamma.o cospi.o bessel_i.o bessel_j.o bessel_k.o bessel_y.o choose.o snorm.o sexp.o dgamma.o pgamma.o qgamma.o rgamma.o dbeta.o pbeta.o qbeta.o rbeta.o dunif.o punif.o qunif.o runif.o dnorm.o pnorm.o qnorm.o rnorm.o dlnorm.o plnorm.o qlnorm.o rlnorm.o df.o pf.o qf.o rf.o dnf.o dt.o pt.o qt.o rt.o dnt.o dchisq.o pchisq.o qchisq.o rchisq.o rnchisq.o dbinom.o pbinom.o qbinom.o rbinom.o rmultinom.o dcauchy.o pcauchy.o qcauchy.o rcauchy.o dexp.o pexp.o qexp.o rexp.o dgeom.o pgeom.o qgeom.o rgeom.o dhyper.o phyper.o qhyper.o rhyper.o dnbinom.o pnbinom.o qnbinom.o rnbinom.o dpois.o ppois.o qpois.o rpois.o dweibull.o pweibull.o qweibull.o rweibull.o dlogis.o plogis.o qlogis.o rlogis.o dnchisq.o pnchisq.o qnchisq.o dnbeta.o pnbeta.o qnbeta.o pnf.o pnt.o qnf.o qnt.o ptukey.o qtukey.o toms708.o wilcox.o signrank.o
ranlib libnmath.a
make[4]: Leaving directory `/data/mbp15ja/R-3.4.1/R-3.4.1/src/nmath'
make[3]: *** No rule to make target `../extra/tre/libtre.a', needed by `libR.so'.  Stop.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/data/mbp15ja/R-3.4.1/R-3.4.1/src/main'
make[2]: *** [R] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/data/mbp15ja/R-3.4.1/R-3.4.1/src/main'
make[1]: *** [R] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/data/mbp15ja/R-3.4.1/R-3.4.1/src'
make: *** [R] Error 1
```

I read in here https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV36656 that the library isn't supposed to make libtre.a and that they assume the file they are looking for is libtre.so
I therefore built the libtre and linked libtre.so from the library to src/extra/tre/libtre.a and now the make

"make -n" now fails with:

```
if test -f ./NAMESPACE;  then \
          /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./NAMESPACE ../../../library/compiler; \
        fi
rm -f ../../../library/compiler/Meta/nsInfo.rds
if test -f DESCRIPTION; then \
          if test "" != ""; then \
            echo "tools:::.install_package_description('.', '../../../library/compiler', '')" | \
            R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES=NULL R_ENABLE_JIT=0 ../../../bin/R --vanilla --slave > /dev/null ; \
          else \
          echo "tools:::.install_package_description('.', '../../../library/compiler')" | \
          R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES=NULL R_ENABLE_JIT=0 ../../../bin/R --vanilla --slave > /dev/null ; \
          fi; \
        fi
make[4]: Leaving directory `/data/mbp15ja/R-3.4.1/R-3.4.1/src/library/compiler'
make mklazycomp
make[4]: Entering directory `/data/mbp15ja/R-3.4.1/R-3.4.1/src/library/compiler'
make[4]: *** No rule to make target `all.R', needed by `../../../library/compiler/R/compiler.rdb'.  Stop.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/data/mbp15ja/R-3.4.1/R-3.4.1/src/library/compiler'
make[3]: *** [all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/data/mbp15ja/R-3.4.1/R-3.4.1/src/library/compiler'
make[2]: *** [R] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/data/mbp15ja/R-3.4.1/R-3.4.1/src/library'
make[1]: *** [R] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/data/mbp15ja/R-3.4.1/R-3.4.1/src'
make: *** [R] Error 1
```

I haven't seen anything regarding all.R and ../../../library/compiler/R/compiler.rdb

Thanks in advance!